# My while loop in python stopped in first loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop

I have a task:

compare the IDs of two files, if IDs match, copy lat and lon of file b1 to b2.
my code worked with one loop, but in the 2nd loop of the outside while it run just the outside while skip the inside while. what can I do?

```
file1=open("b1.csv",mode='r',encoding='utf-8')
file2=open("b2.csv",mode='r+',encoding='utf-8')
header1 = file1.readline()
header2 = file2.readline()

row1 = file1.readline()

while row1 != "":
    row2 = file2.readline()
    rowlist1 = row1.split(",")
    while row2 != "":
        rowlist2 = row2.split(',')
        if rowlist2[0] == rowlist1[0]:
            rowlist2[2] = rowlist1[2]
            rowlist2[3] = rowlist1[3]

            print(rowlist1,rowlist2)
        
        row2 = file2.readline()
    print(rowlist1)
    row1 = file1.readline()
```

file1:

```
ID,name,lon,lat
1345,name1,123.6,20.3
5436,name2,123.7,25.6
5765,name3,212.3,21.2
3424,name4,154.5,23.3
```

file2:

```
ID,name,lon,lat
1345,name1,,
5436,name2,,
5765,name3,,
3424,name4,,
```

Comment: @Ganyu Simp consider using [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) from the standard library

Comment: the original is .xlsx files but I heard that need to convert to .csv files

Answer (score 0):

What you seem to be trying to do would be very inefficient if the files are large. If we assume that both files can be stored (concurrently) in memory, then converting them to dictionaries would make the processing easier and more efficient.

```
CH = "__ch__" # dummy key for the column headers

def asdict(filename, include_header=False):
    d = {}
    with open(filename) as data:
        for i, line in enumerate(map(str.strip, data)):
            if i:
                _id, *vals = line.split(',')
                d[_id] = vals
            elif include_header:
                d[CH] = line
    return d

B1 = "b1.csv"
B2 = "b2.csv"

d1 = asdict(B1)
d2 = asdict(B2, True)

for k, v in d1.items():
    if k in d2:
        # copy the longitude and latitude but not the name
        d2[k][1:] = v[1:]

# rewrite the b2 file
with open(B2, "w") as data:
    print(d2.pop(CH), file=data)
    for k, v in d2.items():
        print(",".join([k]+v), file=data)
```